# Delete Messages with Python Discord bot?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Python Discord Bot that firstly can delete messages within a channel. I wanted it to be Terminator 3 themed so it would start out by the user saying Skynet then the bot asks to activate Y or N? and when the user types Y it would delete all the messages in the channel if the user typed N it would say judgment day is inevitable. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

token = 'Token'

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')


@client.event
  async def on_ready():
     print("Skynet Online")

@client.event

  async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'skynet':
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Execute Y/N?')

@asyncio.coroutine
  async def delete_messages(messages):
    if message.content == 'Y':
        await client.delete_messages()


client.run('Token')
```

Comment: What is the exact problem that is occuring? You never asked a specific question for people to answer.

Comment: the message content or response 'Y' doesn't trigger the bot to delete messages. However, the first message when typing skynet does make the bot output the Y or N?

Comment: There are already a few questions around about using [`Client.wait_for_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_message) to have interactive commands.

Answer (score 2):

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

@has_permissions(manage_messages=True, read_message_history=True)
@bot_has_permissions(manage_messages=True, read_message_history=True)
async def purge(ctx, limit: int = 100, user: d.Member = None, *, matches: str = None):
    """Purge all messages, optionally from ``user``
    or contains ``matches``."""
    logger.info('purge', extra={'ctx': ctx})
    def check_msg(msg):
        if msg.id == ctx.message.id:
            return True
        if user is not None:
            if msg.author.id != user.id:
                return False
        if matches is not None:
            if matches not in msg.content:
                return False
        return True
    deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit, check=check_msg)
    msg = await ctx.send(i18n(ctx, 'purge', len(deleted)))
    await a.sleep(2)
    await msg.delete()
```

That is the command to delete messages

Comment: This is for the newer [tag:discord.py-rewrite] branch. The code in the question above is from the older async branch (note `send_message` over `send`, etc.)